# urllib keeps freezing while trying to pull HTML data from a website - is my code correct?

Tags: python, macos, parsing, urllib, python-3.4

I'm trying to build a simple Python script algorithm on Mac OS X that has four parts to it.

1. go to a defined website and grab all the HTML using `urllib`
2. parse the HTML data to find a table of numbers (using `beautifulsoup`)
3. with those numbers do a simple calculation
4. print out the results in a table in numerical order

I'm having trouble with step 1, i can grab the data with `urllib` using this code

```
import urllib.request
y=urllib.request.urlopen('my target website url')
x=y.read()
print(x)
```

But it keeps freezing once it has returned the HTML and the Python shell is non-responsive.

Comment: requests looks like it might be a better option for what I'm trying to achieve... all advise welcomed

Comment: Are you sure that's not just the shell struggling with the amount of text you're asking it to `print`? What if you actually try to parse it instead?

Comment: So if i parse the html for the specific data I'm looking for, before print, it should reduce the load on the shell which may stop it from freezing?

Comment: Potentially. Or just try `print(x[:100])` to see whether that's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you mentioned requests, I think it's a great solution.

```
import requests
import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('http://example.com')
html = r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
table = soup.find("table", {"id": "targettable"})
```

As suggested by jonrsharpe, if you're concerned about the size of the response returned by that url, you can check the size first before printing or parsing.

With requests:

```
r = requests.get('http://example.com')
print r.headers['content-length']
```

Comment: i've run 
    easy_install requests 

and i've restarted my machine, but i continue to get the error 
   ImportError: No module named 'requests'

i consulted another page but everything i have tried so far gets me back to this same error. 

thank you for your help 

Comment: i found the problem, i needed to run
    `python3.4 -m pip install requests`

Comment: @twiggygarcia note that you could probably also do `pip3 install requests`